# Trouble passing an ArrayList of objects from one class to another

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist

I'm trying to display two ArrayLists on a JTextArea but am having troubles passing an ArrayList of objects from one class to another.

The part of the code I'm having problems with is trying to display the info with the following code

```
private void jButtonDisplayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                               
    {                                                   
        for(int i=0; i<bars.size(); i++)
        {
            jTextAreaDisplay.append(jTextAreaDisplay.getText() 
                    + bars.get(i).toString() + bars.get(i).getLiquor.toString() 
                    + "\n\n");

        }
    }
```

It says that it can't find the symbol: variable getLiquor from my Bar class.

Bar Class code where I'm trying to pass it:

```
ArrayList<Liquor> liquors;
private Liquor liquor = new Liquor(liquors);
public Liquor getLiquor()
    {
        return liquor;
    }
```

From my other class Liquor:

```
ArrayList<Liquor> liquors = new ArrayList<>();  
public Liquor(ArrayList<Liquor> liquors)
{
    this.liquors = liquors;
    this.vodka = getV();
    this.whiskey = getW();
    this.rum = getR();
    this.gin = getG();
    this.brandy = getB();
    this.vCount = getVC();
    this.wCount = getWC();
    this.rCount = getRC();
    this.gCount = getGC();
    this.bCount = getBC();
}
```

The other contructor in my Liquor code (if relevant):

```
public Liquor(String vodka, String whiskey, String rum, String gin, 
            String brandy, int v, int w, int r, int g, int b)
    {
        this.vodka = vodka;
        this.whiskey = whiskey;
        this.rum = rum;
        this.gin = gin;
        this.brandy = brandy;
        this.vCount = v;
        this.wCount = w;
        this.rCount = r;
        this.gCount = g;
        this.bCount = b;
    }
```

#### Update

From what I can see, I changed it a little bit and at least the names of the liquor show, but the stock number for each isn't been read in, instead it shows it as null. I think the problem lies here:

```
public Liquor(ArrayList<Liquor> liquors)
    {

        this.vodka = "Vodka";
        this.whiskey = "Whiskey";
        this.rum = "Rum";
        this.gin = "Gin";
        this.brandy = "Brandy";
        this.vCount = getVC();
        this.wCount = getWC();
        this.rCount = getRC();
        this.gCount = getGC();
        this.bCount = getBC();
    }
```

I don't think my getters are working correctly. Or maybe the ArrayList?

Output:

> The Kendall bar is named: Kink 
>   Live music: true 
>   Food Service: false
>   Liquor currently in stock:
>
> Vodka: 0
>
> Whiskey: 0
>
> Rum: 0
>
> Gin: 0
>
> Brandy: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing parentheses by the `getLiquor` method call:

```
bars.get(i).toString() + bars.get(i).getLiquor().toString()
```

Comment: WOW, I can't believe I missed that! Thank you very much.

Comment: Okay, so now, the problem is that my output doesn't show the liquor name or number entered...

Comment: @diggz you haven't posted any code that would do that.

Comment: @diggz still no output code. Did you implement `toString()`?

Comment: I think I see the problem. When I call this.vCount = getVC(); it's returning itself, which is null. I need to return the value within the ArrayList, not the class variable. Ideas?